# Re-style entire Leaflet vector map on event

Tags: leaflet

I want to restyle every feature on a vectorgrid. The specific problem is when you select a section of a bus route, potentially by just a mouse-over, i want to light up all the sections which contain common routes. I have a style callback function. How do I tell Leaflet that I have changed the rules on what colours to use etc.

Comment: RTFM http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.VectorGrid/vectorgrid-api-docs.html under "Updating Styles"

Comment: the short answer to this is "don't".. you can resyle specific id's. if you wan to do the whole map they will have to be one, or a defined set, of feature ids. I have built myself feature specific tile sets, z/x/y/s i dont know how many we can handle of these but i am sure we can have at least 10 and it will be OK, just quite a few nul requests bouncing about, but with vectors you are gong to be get that anyway.